# (React) Dynamically display content based on state variable depending on another State variable

Tags: javascript, reactjs

What I require is to display only a portion of an array of blog objects both of which (the ones I want to display and an array of all blog objects) are defined as a state variable using React hooks. This blog array is modified by form submissions and initialized by accessing a REST API endpoint (`blogService` is implemented using Axios).

The issue I'm facing is that while this blog array is being updated on the form submission, the array of objects that I do want to display is not.

Relevant code:

```js
const [blogs, setBlogs] = useState([])
const [user, setUser] = useState(null)
const [currBlog, setCurrBlog] = useState(init_dict)
const [dispBlog, setDispBlog] = useState(null)

...

useEffect(() => {
    blogService.getAll().then(blogs => setBlogs(blogs))
  }, [])


useEffect(() => {
    setDispBlog(blogs.filter(b => b.user.username === user.username))
  }, [blogs, user])

const addBlog = async (event) => {
    event.preventDefault()
    let savedBlog
    try {
      savedBlog = await blogService.addBlog(currBlog)
    } catch (err) {
      console.log('err', err)
    }

    console.log('savedBlog', savedBlog)
    const newBlogs = blogs.concat(savedBlog)
    setBlogs(newBlogs)
    setCurrBlog(init_dict)
    console.log('newBlogs', newBlogs)
    console.log('dispBlog', dispBlog)
  }

return (<div> {blogs.map(blog => <p key={blog.id}>{blog.content}</p>)  // updated}
              {dispBlog.map(blog => <p key={blog.id}>{blog.content}</p) // is not updated})
```

The state variable array `blogs` is updated and dynamically rendered, but `dispBlog` is not.

I have tried converting `dispBlog` to a non-state variable, which is updated openly, but that too seems not to work.

Forgive me for not having used proper terminologies, and I realize a lot of the code is written poorly (especially mixing the use of await and then but neither of the two seem to work)

Comment: *"The state variable array blogs is updated and dynamically rendered but dispBlog is not."* What makes you think that? Note that your `console.log('dispBlog', dispBlog);` in `addBlog` will be misleading. The component function hasn't run again yet, and state updates are asynchronous. But when it *does* run, your effect callback will run (because `blogs` changed), which will update `dispBlog`. (That said, I wouldn't use an effect for this, I'd just update it at the same time I'm updating `blogs`.)

Comment: If something *other* than that misleading `console.log` is making you think `dispBlog` isn't getting updated, please update your question with a runnable [mcve] demonstrating the problem using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button). Stack Snippets support React, including JSX; [here's how to do one](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338537/).